# Ошибка вывода данных из servlet в JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

проблема следующая, пытаюсь отобразить данные переданные как список "List". Но получаю ошибку

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is
>   not native or abstract in class file
>   javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagSupport

С чем связанно тоже не могу понять.
Вот код **servlet**:

```
List<Roll> list = new ArrayList<Roll>();

while (resultSets.next())
  {
   Roll roll = new Roll();

   roll.setNumbern(resultSets.getInt(1));

   roll.setRollnum(resultSets.getInt(2));

   roll.setTimer(resultSets.getDate(4));

   list.add(roll);

   request.setAttribute("name",list);
  }
request.getRequestDispatcher("4kl/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Вот **JSP**:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:forEach items="${name}" var="n">
  <tr>
    <td>${n.Numbern}</td>
    <td>${n.Rollnum}</td>
    <td>${n.Timer}</td>
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Класс **Roll**:

```
public class Roll implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int Numbern;

    private int Rollnum;

    private Date Timer;

    public int getNumbern() {
        return Numbern;
    }

    public void setNumbern(int numbern)
    {
        Numbern = numbern;
    }

    public int getRollnum()
    {
        return Rollnum;
    }

    public void setRollnum(int rollnum)
    {
        Rollnum = rollnum;
    }

    public Date getTimer()
    {
        return Timer;
    }

    public void setTimer(Date timer)
    {
        Timer = timer;
    }

    public  Roll (){}

}
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ua.asutp</groupId>
  <artifactId>mymvn</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <dependencies>

<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
         <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.2.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>javaee</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>local-oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.11.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>cglib</groupId>
   <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
   <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

 </dependencies>


 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
           <source>1.5</source>
           <target>1.5</target>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.1</version>
           <configuration>
           <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build> 
</project>
```

Возможно я что-то пропустил при вызове **c:forEach** Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Может есть способ получше JSTL ? Я только учусь, поэтому мне хотелось бы знать как правильнее выводить данные. Спасибо. Все еще актуально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ответ, просто пометка:

```
request.setAttribute("name",list);
```

эту строчку вытащите из цикла,добавить то надо всего 1 раз

---

Ещё один момент по поводу зависимости

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

в центральном репозитории я не смог найти такого, попробуйте взять более новую версию, например 4:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

эту зависимость тоже стоит обновить. Нет такой версии 5, может быть где-то есть 5,0 но по идее это вам должна была IDE показать

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Вы помогли решить мою проблему а именно, поменял зависимости как вы сказали и все поехало как по маслу. По поводу `request.setAttribute("name",list);` какраз мне и нужно получить все значения из БД поэтому там не 1 строка а больше. Уберите пожалуйста эту запись, что бы не путать в будущем людей. Тему считаю закрытой. Спасибо вам большое за помощь.

Comment: и по поводу награды в +100 баллов, то их можно вручить через 13 часов. Как только будет доступно я обязательно сделаю подтверждение.

Comment: @Ethernets я к тому, что в цикле вы собираете их в лист. Добавить на странницу логичнее после сборки, т.к. в вашем варианте вы просто каждый раз перезатераете атрибут новым значением.

Comment: не покажите приблизительно ?

Comment: Просто если я вынесу этот атрибут за цикл то тогда у меня будут постоянно одни и тежи числа

Comment: Аааа я сразу не обратил внимание, да вы правы. Просто тот кусок кода что я приложил я делал как тестовый для показа. Поэтому допустил ошибку. В оригинале все чучуть иначе )))) В оригинале `request.setAttribute("name",list);` За скобками все верно вы говорите. Еще раз большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить реализацию JSTL в зависимости.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Удали

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>jstl</groupId> 
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Добрый день, добавил вашу зависимость. Проблема не прошла. Прилагаю **pom.xml**

Comment: @Ethernets обновил ответ.

Comment: Проблема не решилась. Какие еще будут варианты ?

Comment: @Ethernets обновил ответ

Comment: Я удалил сразу как вы написали про добавление второй зависимости. Проблема осталась на том же уровне.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в том что вы называете переменные не по правилам (c большой буквы как классы и jsp не может правильно определить геттеры). Попробуйте так:

```
public class Roll implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int numbern;

    private int rollnum;

    private Date timer;
...
}
```

и

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:forEach items="${name}" var="n">
  <tr>
    <td>${n.numbern}</td>
    <td>${n.rollnum}</td>
    <td>${n.timer}</td>
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

**P.S.** В любом случае, лучше следовать стандартным правилам для имен переменных, констант и классов в Java, иначе остальным программистам  сильно некомфортно читать ваш код.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема осталась прежней. По поводу обьявления переменных, прошу прощения, просто на C# иначе. Может есть другой способ без использования JSTL ? как вообще правильно выводить информацию с сервлета в JSP ?

Comment: @Ethernets JSTL это и есть правильный способ. Скриптлеты не рекомендуются

Comment: @Alex78191 на данный момент нет возможности выложить файл зависимостей. Но то что там зависимость на jstl версии 1.2 была это 100%

Comment: Завтра добавлю что вы просите. И пропишу зависимость которую вы предложили. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: А запускаете ли вы код в JEE application server'e? И если да, то в каком?

Comment: @Ethernets Наверное вы добавили зависимость `jstl`, то есть только API без реализации.

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin Да Tomcat 8